# Add delete row in jquery wordpress issue

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

Hi there i make meta box with jQuery in wordpress. I am trying to add more than one meta boxes with jQuery.

It works all perfectly, it add meta fields and save data, remove meta fields and remove data.

but the issue is that the remove button is also shown on first (default) meta filed, when i click on remove, it remove first (default) meta field, i dont want remove button on First row.

And second issue is, when i remove the field and update the post the data in this meta field is delete but the meta field does not rove from there

My Code:

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_multiple_urls');

function add_multiple_urls($post) {
    add_meta_box( 'multiple-urls-id', 'Download Links', 'repeatable_download_link', 'post', 'normal', 'default');
}

function repeatable_download_link($post) {

    $repeatable_fields = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'repeatable_fields', true);

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        $('#add-row').on('click', function() {
            var row = $('.empty-row.screen-reader-text').clone(true);
            row.removeClass('empty-row screen-reader-text');
            row.insertBefore('#repeatable-fieldset-one tbody>tr:last');
            return false;
        });

        $('.remove-row').on('click', function() {
            $(this).parents('tr').remove();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<table id="repeatable-fieldset-one" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="92%" align="left">URL</th>
            <th width="8%"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        if($repeatable_fields ) :
            foreach($repeatable_fields as $field ) {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="widefat" name="url[]" value="<?php if ($field['url'] != '') echo esc_attr( $field['url'] ); else echo 'http://'; ?>" />
            </td>
            <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">Remove</a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
                }
            else :
            // show a blank one
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="url[]" value="http://" /></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <!-- empty hidden one for jQuery -->
        <tr class="empty-row screen-reader-text">
            <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="url[]" value="http://" /></td>
            <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">Remove</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p><a id="add-row" class="button" href="#">Add another</a></p>
<?php
}

add_action('save_post', 'save_multiple_download_link');
function save_multiple_download_link() {
    global $post;

    $old = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'repeatable_fields', true);
    $new = array();
    $urls = $_POST['url'];
    $count = count( $urls );

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
        if($urls[$i] == 'http://' ){
            $new[$i]['url'] = '';
        }
        else{
            $new[$i]['url'] = stripslashes( $urls[$i] ); // and however you want to sanitize
        }
    }

    if(!empty($new) && $new != $old)
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'repeatable_fields', $new);
    elseif(empty($new) && $old)
        delete_post_meta($post->ID, 'repeatable_fields', $old);
}
?>
```

Comment: If you don't want default field to have remove button, remove it?

    `<tr><td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="url[]" value="http://" /></td></tr>`

After updating post, you need to remove those that are not submitted. Else, it will still be in `$repeatable_fields`.

Comment: Thanx @josephting, my first issue is fixed what about second issue

Comment: I don't know how you're doing the processing after post update. You might want to post the code here. Maybe you could try to remove all the fields that's saved in the post, then update all the fields content you just submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. The first issue should be fixed already by just removing the remove button.

```
<?php
  }
else :
// show a blank one
?>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="url[]" value="http://" /></td>
</tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

For second issue, the meta field is removed but you're adding empty/default meta field back into the post_meta. You don't want to add empty field into `$new`.

Use this instead.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
  if($urls[$i] != 'http://' ){
    $new[$i]['url'] = stripslashes( $urls[$i] ); // and however you want to sanitize
  }
}
```

If you still want to have an empty/default field at the end, you can add an blank field after the `foreach` loop and you might want to add the remove button back on this one.

```
<?php
  if($repeatable_fields ) :
    foreach($repeatable_fields as $field ) {
?>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="widefat" name="url[]" value="<?php if ($field['url'] != '') echo esc_attr( $field['url'] ); else echo 'http://'; ?>" />
    </td>
    <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">Remove</a></td>
  </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="url[]" value="http://" /></td>
    <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">Remove</a></td>
  </tr>
<?php
  else :
    // show a blank one
?>
```

Comment: Thanx alot @josephting thank u very much...i also delete some more lines